# Parted input/output error while making a new GPT table

Tags: usb, gparted, gpt, badblocks, parted

I have damaged usb drive. Tried making a new table with GParted, not finishing the operation. also tried with parted, it's printing input/output error while making GPT table.

scanned with `badblocks` by `-w` parameter, printed tons of numbers.

Comment: Damaged and badlocks says it all. Not usable, not reliable. Throw it in the trash. No reason to create a new GPT table, as any data you store on this drive may be lost without warning.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use gdisk (`sudo apt install gdisk` if you don't have it):

(Remember to unmount the usb first, e.g. `umount /dev/sdxn`)

```
$ gdisk /dev/sdx

> x     # expert mode

> z     # zap (destroy) GPT data structures and exit
```

(press yes when prompted)

```
$ gdisk /dev/sdx

> o     # create a new empty GUID partition table (GPT)

> w     # write Changes
```

You can find out the correct device (sdx) by typing `lsblk` for example.

If it has worked this far, you can try to add partitions with gparted or any other software you like.

Comment: I answared to main topic, can you return?

Comment: also tried with dd for writing zeros, but printing error no enough space.